# How to deal with grid in different layout with Material Ui

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui, frontend, jsx

I am pretty sure that lot's of people asked the same question, but I did not find the answer, sorry.

I am trying to understand how to use grid with Material-ui.

This is a picture to explain my problem :
[Picture which explain my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgaZu.jpg)

So, my window has the 12 standard columns of Material UI.

In this window, the red part (1) is taking 2 columns.
The other big part (2) is taking 10 columns.

In the second part, I've got several blue elements which are taking 3 columns per element.

How can I design my blue element to take all times "3 columns of the full window" and not "3 column of the parent element" ?

Because, at this time I can code :

Red part = 2 columns

Big part = 10 columns

Blue element = 3 columns of the 10 columns Big part

But I cannot say :
Blue element = 3 columns of the full window

I can use CSS vw property and add margins, but I guess there is a way to use only Material-ui Grid, isn't it ?

I hope to be clear in my problems.

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

That can be solved with nesting [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#nested-grid) or [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const { Grid, Paper } = window.MaterialUI;

const App = () => {

return <Grid className="grid" wrap="wrap" container direction="row">
<Grid style={{flex: '1'}} container direction="column" justify="center">
  <Paper style={{border: '1px solid white', background: 'red', flex: '1'}} elevation={3}/>
  <Paper style={{border: '1px solid white', background: 'red', flex: '1'}} elevation={3}/>
</Grid>
<Grid style={{flex: '2 1 0'}}  wrap="wrap" container direction="row">
   {[...Array(9).keys()].map(pr => 
    <Paper key={pr} style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', border: '1px solid white', flex: '1 1 32%'}} />
   )}
</Grid>
</Grid>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#root, .grid {
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-ui-lab-umd@4.0.0-alpha.32/material-ui-lab.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```